# Rails 4, character # in routes not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have 2 routes as following:

```
get '/abc' => 'ctrl#index'
get '/#/abc' => 'ctrl#index'
```

Seems 2nd route '#/abc' not works

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If I'm correct,in `get '/#/abc'`,the position where the `#` is placed,is actually the place for giving `controller name`(for example `get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'`),so it wont work.What you are actually trying to do? Why you need that `#`?

Comment: Fragment part of URI is not sent to web server. So if you are trying to process url like `http://domain.com/#/abc`, the server receives only `http://domain.com/`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `#` route?

Comment: I use angular combination with. In ie 9,10 auto insert '#' to url, so when use copy and paste to address bar...rails won't work (rails don't get params)
I want to 2 routes above connect to 1 controller action. but this is can't :)